# How can I implement a String variable instead of 'Landschaft'?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a `SpinnerActivity`, which looks like following:

> http://img4.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/bildschirmfotovse8j4po1t.png

Now for example if I select 'Landschaft' (in English: landscape) I want to search in the `DatabaseHandler.java` for a location which is in the category 'Landschaft' (landscape)

Therefore I have written the following method in `DatabaseHandler.java`:

In this method, I have just written Kategorie = Landscape.

However I want, that the selected `SpinnerArray` (Landschaft, Brücken...etc.) in my Spinner would be inserted in my `DatabaseHandler` instead of "Landschaft", how can I do that?

```
public List<Position> getAllPositionsWithCategory() {
        List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<Position>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POSITIONS
                + " WHERE Kategorie = 'Landschaft'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

                Position position = new Position();

                position.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));

                position.setName(cursor.getString(1));

                position.setKategorie(cursor.getString(2));

                position.setLaenge(cursor.getFloat(3));

                position.setBreite(cursor.getFloat(4));

                // Adding position to list

                positionList.add(position);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the the fixed String with `?` in your query, and pass the value to be inserted in the second argument of `db.rawQuery()`.

The following might work for your case:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_POSITIONS
            + " WHERE Kategorie = ?";
// ...
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { "Landschaft" });
```

You can now replace your String `"Landschaft"` with a variable of your choice.

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])